# change the two columns of a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

The code is as the following.

```
a=0;
>> b=[4 0];
>> a([2,1])=b
```

The answer is:

```
a=[0 4].
```

My question is: How come we can change the size of the matrix a when we make the assignment (since the original size of a is 1 by 1 and now the size of a is 1 by 2)? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you initially assigned a to be a single number (1 by 1), trying to access the index a([2,1])  should get you Index exceeds matrix dimensions, since a is 1 by 1. The way Matlab treats the problem however, is that when you re-assigned b to equal to some index of a, that index is allocated and the structure of a is also changed. Which allows you to do a(:,1) = b or any other indexing as long as the data fits.

if

```
b = [0 4; 4 0];
```

which is a 2 dimensional data, you will not be able to do a([2,1]) = b, since the index allocated is 1 dimension. However, you could allocate a 2 dimensional index for b by doing something like:

```
a(:,:,1)=b
```